# why do the overlapped cardviews in Recyclerview not coming at the center of the screen in android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

So, I am trying to display all the cards saved in the database overlapped on each other with each card tilted left and right alternatively . So the cards are getting overlapped and tilted like I wanted alternatively but they are not coming at the center of the screen but towards the center right and right side if the cards not visible on the screen like this [image: How it's displaying]

Below is the customised overlappingLayoutManager code and the XML layout files
1)**OverlappingLayoutManager.kt**

```
class OverlappingLayoutManager(context: Context) : RecyclerView.LayoutManager() {
    private val horizontalOverlap =
        context.resources.getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.card_horizontal_overlap)
    private val verticalOverlap =
        context.resources.getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.card_vertical_overlap)
    private val tiltAngle = 5f // Adjust the tilt angle as needed

    override fun generateDefaultLayoutParams(): LayoutParams {
        return LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        )
    }

    override fun onLayoutChildren(recycler: RecyclerView.Recycler?, state: RecyclerView.State?) {
        if (itemCount == 0) {
            removeAndRecycleAllViews(recycler!!)
            return
        }

        detachAndScrapAttachedViews(recycler!!)

        val leftTilt = tiltAngle
        val rightTilt = -tiltAngle
        var currentTilt = leftTilt

        for (position in 0 until itemCount) {
            val view = recycler.getViewForPosition(position)
            addView(view)
            measureChildWithMargins(view, 0, 0)
            val width = getDecoratedMeasuredWidth(view)
            val height = getDecoratedMeasuredHeight(view)

            layoutDecoratedWithMargins(
                view,
                width - (position * horizontalOverlap),
                height - (position * verticalOverlap),
                width + (width - (position * horizontalOverlap)),
                height + (height - (position * verticalOverlap))
            )

            view.rotation = currentTilt
            currentTilt = if (currentTilt == leftTilt) rightTilt else leftTilt
        }
    }
}
```

The xml file **fragment_to_learn_flash_cards.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@drawable/flash_tablebar"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/back_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:text="Do the practise " />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/emojiBounce"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_width="34dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/emoji" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/emptyImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        tools:listitem="@layout/recycle_view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/emptyImage"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**recycle_view.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_cardview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textLeft"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Swipe left if you learnt word"
            android:textColor="#00e676"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textRight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Swipe right if you haven't"
            android:textColor="#d32f2f"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/word1"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#FFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/word2"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#FFFF"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The fragment class where overlappingLayoutManager class is put **ToLearnFlashCards.kt**

```
class ToLearnFlashCards : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding:FragmentToLearnFlashCardsBinding
    lateinit var bottomNav:BottomNavigationView
    val cardViewmodel:  FlashCardViewmodel by viewModels{
        WordViewModelFactory((requireActivity().application as MyApp).repository)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        binding = FragmentToLearnFlashCardsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater,container,false)

        //Taking the bOTTOMNavigation view instance from Activity into Fragment
        bottomNav = (activity as? FirstScreen)?.findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView)!!
        bottomNav.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        // Bounce animation for emojiBounce view
        val bounceAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(
            binding.emojiBounce,
            "translationX",
            0f,
            -100f,
            0f
        ).apply {
            duration = 2000 // Set the duration of the animation
            repeatCount = ObjectAnimator.INFINITE // Set the repeat count for infinite bouncing
            repeatMode = ObjectAnimator.REVERSE // Reverse the animation after each repeat
        }

        // Start the bounce animation
        bounceAnimator.start()

        binding.backIcon.setOnClickListener {
           findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_toLearnFlashCards_to_flashCards)
        }

        val adapter = FlashcardpaiAdapter { cardPair ->
            cardViewmodel.deleteCards(cardPair)

        }
        binding.recyclerview.adapter = adapter

        //Swipe Gesture

        val itemTouchHelper = ItemTouchHelper(object :ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(
            0,ItemTouchHelper.LEFT or ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT
        ){
            override fun onMove(
                recyclerView: RecyclerView,
                viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
                target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            ): Boolean {
                return false
            }
            override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
                val position = viewHolder.adapterPosition
                val cardPair = adapter.currentList[position]
                // Handle swipe left to delete the card
                cardViewmodel.deleteCards(cardPair)
            }
        })
        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(binding.recyclerview)

        binding.recyclerview.layoutManager = OverlappingLayoutManager(binding.root.context)
      //  binding.recyclerview.rotation=10f

        //Observe  the data changes for the items added
        cardViewmodel.allWords.observe(requireActivity()) { cardPairs ->

                adapter.submitList(cardPairs)

                if (cardPairs.isEmpty()){
                    binding.emptyImage.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }else{
                    binding.emptyImage.visibility = View.GONE
                }
            }

        return binding.root
    }

}
```

below is the **dimens.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="default_margin">15dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="card_horizontal_overlap">26dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="card_vertical_overlap">26dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

The card are getting displayin this way. I want cards to be displayed close to similar manner [image: How I want to display]